# How to represent the coefficients of a multi layer perception neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

For learning purposes, I'm trying to code from stratch a simple multi layer perceptron (MLP) neural network, with:

- 2500 inputs in the input layer,
- 100 neurons in hidden layer's #1 and #2,
- and 10 outputs in the output layer

and backpropagation, without using tensorflow or such ready to use tools.

Each neuron in the hidden layer #1 has to be connected to the 2500 inputs and requires to store 2500 coefficients. The same applies for all neurons of all layers.

**Question: which datastructure is usually used to store all the coefficients from the neurons of layer n-1 to specific neurons of layer n?**

Is there a unique data structure (for example in Numpy) that can store all these coefficients for the whole MLP?

Is a tensor (n dim array) mandatory for such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neural networks are mostly just a series of matrix multiplications, and non linear transformations. Hence n dimensional arrays are the natural storage method. Depending on the application you could use a sparse matrix which stores coeficients and indeces of those coeficients. But in general the storage is just matrices.

A good peak under the hood of libraries like tensorflow is to look at/implement a [neural network in numpy](https://www.python-course.eu/neural_networks_with_python_numpy.php).

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so don't forget to accept the answer, if not clarify why :)